# Converting hashtable to array of strings

Tags: powershell

How can I convert a hashtable to an array of strings?
Suppose $l_table is a hashtable. If I try

```
$l_array = $l_table | format-table
```

then $l_array is an array, but an array of "FormatEntryData" objects.
If I do

```
[string[]]$l_array = $l_table | format-table
```

then $l_array is an array of strings, but the strings are all "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData".  If I try

```
$l_array = $l_table | out-string
```

then $l_array is a single string.  I've tried lots of other things, but nothing works, short of manually looping through, which I really don't want to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[string[]]$l_array = $l_table | out-string -stream
```

Answer (score 38):

[David I. McIntosh's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21413763/45375) works well, but it should be noted that the elements of the resulting array correspond to *all* lines of the default output, which includes:

- the empty leading and trailing lines
- the two header lines (the line with the column names and the separator line)

`Out-String` simply sends what you'd normally see in the console (terminal) to a string, by default as a *single* string, and with `-Stream` as an *array* of strings (lines).

Here's a variation of David's command that removes both the header and the empty lines:

```
[string[]] $l_array = ($l_table | Out-String -Stream) -ne '' | select -Skip 2
```

---

The rest of this answer shows **how to *control the specifics* of the string representation obtained**; it uses PS v3+ syntax and built-in alias `%` for `ForEach-Object` for brevity.

<sup>Note: For clarity, the sample input hashtable is called `$ht` (not `$l_table`) in the following examples; the PSv4+ `.ForEach()` variants perform better.</sup>

- Get all **keys** as a string array:

  ```
    [string[]] $ht.Keys
  ```
- Get all **values** as a string array:

  ```
    [string[]] $ht.Values
  ```
- Get a **custom representation** of **key-value pairs**, in format `<key>=<value>`; note that `.GetEnumerator()` is needed to send the key-value pairs *individually* through the pipeline; by default, PowerShell passes a hashtable *as a whole*:

  ```
    $ht.GetEnumerator() | % { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" }

    # or (PSv4+):
    $ht.GetEnumerator().ForEach({ "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" })
  ```

Note that while a `[string]` / `[string[]]` cast, which is also applied *implicitly* during string interpolation (inside `"..."`, an expandable string), works well with [primitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive) .NET types (as well as additional numeric types such as `[decimal]` and `[bigint]`); generally, types will just print their full *type name*, unless their `.ToString()` method is explicitly overridden to return a more meaningful custom representation (which is what the primitive types do and which is the case with only *some* of the non-primitive types returned by PowerShell cmdlets).

Also note that using an array(-like data structure) inside an expandable string expands to the (stringified) elements concatenation of its elements with the value of the (rarely used) `$OFS` preference variable, which defaults to a space char. (e.g., `$a='one', 'two'; "$a"` expands to `'one two'`; that is, it is the equivalent of `"$([string[]] $a -join ' ')"` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for more information on *expandable strings* (string interpolation) in PowerShell.

A simple example of choosing a *property* of a value to represent it in the string:

```
# Sample hashtable containing a value of a non-built-in type,
# [System.Diagnostics.Process]    
$ht = @{ one = 1; two = Get-Process -ID $PID }

# Use the `.Path` property to represent the value.
$ht.GetEnumerator() | % { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value.Path)" }
```

Comment: Actually, my issue was the separation of types into _primitive_ (aka _built-in_) and not _primitive_ which seems to ascribe some privileged status to _primitive_ types (with respect to `ToString()`). My point was that **all** types must override `ToString()` to return, not print (that comes later as does a comment), something other than a string of the type's name (inherited from Object.ToString()). Try `[int32].getmethods() | ft name,isstatic,declaringtype` to see that even a **very** _primitive_ type has defined for itself 4 overloads of `ToString()` (and not allowed any inherited ones).

Comment: @UberKluger The "privileged" status of primitive types is that they're _known_ to provide meaningful representations, but, yes, they too get that behavior from explicitly overridden `.ToString()` methods. It was just a pragmatic way of saying: you can _rely_ on these well-known types (plus a few more) to have meaningful string representations - no general statement can be made for any other types.

Comment: Last comment: Query-how are they _known_ to provide meaningful representations? I can only think of two methods, read the documentation (this includes using reflection on the type definition) or direct testing (aka suck it and see). However, both these methods are equally applicable to **all** types. The fact that we _know_ what an `int` or `bool` "looks like" is only because we have already "seen" it (probably in another environment, e.g. MS BASIC or ECMA-262). Ultimately, the only way to _know_ what a type converted to `String` "looks like" is to "invoke its `ToString()` method (and see)".

Answer (score 3):

The hash is just a Hashtable so it has a keys and a values property.

```
$hash = @{}

$hash["foo"] = "bob"

$hash.Values

$hash.Values | Out-string
```

---

If you want to get the enumerator it will return you the keyvaluepair

```
$hash.GetEnumerator() |%{$_ | out-string}
```

Comment: This only gets the values.

Comment: I updated the answer can you put a few more details I'm not sure what the result your looking for is.

Answer (score 3):

While the original poster might have wanted an array of strings corresponding to the output of **Format-Table**, as the supplied attempts and poster's own answer/comments might suggest, the wording of the question heading is more typical of someone wishing to convert the hash table itself into an array of each item's value (converted to `String` if not already a `String`). For those looking for a solution to this problem I present the following (since there doesn't seem to be a similar question as yet):-

The simplistic answer is to use

```
[string[]]$l_table.values
```

and this does give an array of strings as desired.

Note: `$l_table.values` is a `[System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection]` which is why the conversion to `[string[]]` is necessary even if the values are already strings. For example,

```
'Found {0} with submatch {1}' -f [string[]]$matches.values
```

won't work without it. (The other possible problem is mentioned next.)

The major flaw with `$l_table.values` is that, unless the hash table was defined to be `[ordered]` (PSv3+), the order of the items is undefined (and can change as the hash table is modified). Often, when converting a hash table to an array, it is desired to have a certain ordering of the elements in that array. Indeed, sometimes the keys are (positive) integers and the intent is that the resultant array use the same values as array indexes (see `$matches` example above). To create this type of array, use

```
[string[]]$l_table[($l_table.keys | sort)]
```

or, if the values are already strings, just

```
$l_table[($l_table.keys | sort)]
```

to invoke Powershell's collection slicing functionality (whereby a single expression can produce an array of independently selected collection items by using an array expression as the index. E.g. `$array[1,3,5,9]`, `$array[1,2,3,4,5]` or `$array[1..5]`). Note that this will only produce an array with the keys as the indexes if the keys form a contiguous range starting at 0. However, since the indexing expression is a pipeline, it is possible to get just about anything as the required array of keys. To get a resultant array from a 'sparse' hash table (of non-string values) use

```
[string[]]$l_table[0..($l_table.keys | sort -descending)[0]]
#
# ($l_table.keys | sort -descending) produces a sorted array of key values
# with the largest value in element 0
#
```

Now the resultant array will have the integer keys correctly corresponding to the appropriate index value by having any intervening (unused) array items set to "" (i.e. `[string]$null`). If this is a problem then a two step process can be used to leave the 'missing' entries
as `$null`. Firstly, convert a non-string hash table to strings without adding entries by building a new hash table one dictionary pair at a time (using `GetEnumerator()`). Secondly, don't use `[string[]]` in order to leave `$null` in the 'unused' items when converting the (now string) hash table to an array as follows

```
($l_table.getenumerator() | foreach -begin {$str_table = @{}} -process {$str_table.add($_.key,[string]$_.value)} -end {$str_table[0..($str_table.keys | sort -descending)[0]]})
```

or perhaps more efficiently (by removing the potentially costly sort)

```
($l_table.getenumerator() | foreach -begin {$maxkey = 0; $str_table = @{}} -process {$str_table.add($_.key,[string]$_.value); if ($maxkey -lt $_.key){$maxkey = $_.key}} -end {$str_table[0..$maxkey]})
```

Note: for a sparse hash table of string values the initial form without conversion

```
$l_table[0..($l_table.keys | sort -descending)[0]]
```

will work but the use of `[string[]]` will change any missing entries from `$null` to `""` if desired.

Comment: All good solutions, albeit to a slightly different problem than I was originally trying to solve.

Comment: ```[string[]]$hash.values``` is the most simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem; Hashtable must be retrieved by either keys or values but you can't get a collection of pairs - that is what the original hashtable is, after all. In my example, the hashtable is represented by a "Dictionary" (you will remember from VBS :-). However you will need to determine a separator to delimit keys & values, in this case "Key<->Value"

```
$ARRAY = ( $DICT.Keys | foreach-object { "$_<->$($DICT[$_])"})
```

You can even sort the keys first if you want. In this case I reversed to Value<--->Key and sorted by values. I've also expanded the string a little to make more verbose but legible:

```
$ARRAY = ( $DICT.Keys | foreach-object { $DICT[$_] + "<--->" + $_} | sort-object)
```

Comment: Re "Hashtable must be retrieved by either keys or values but you can't get a collection of pairs": Yes, you can: `$DICT.GetEnumerator()`